# How to rank a matrix by twenty percent lower occurrences?

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a `list` with 33 `matrices`. Here is a `matrix` example:

```
a <- matrix(c(0.44, 0.33, 0.43, 0.54, 0.42, 0.49, 0.48, 0.51, 0.48, 0.55, 0.35, 0.51, 0.50, 0.34, 0.37), 1,15)
colnames(a) <- c("ACES4", "AMBV4", "ARCZ6", "BBAS3", "BBDC4", "BRAP4", "BRKM5", "BRTP3", "BRTP4", "CESP5", "CGAS5", "CLSC4", "CMIG3", "CMIG4", "DASA3")
```

I need to know what are the twenty percent lower values. In this case, will be `3` values (there are 15 values so 20% is 3 right...):

```
print(a[,c(2,11,14)])
AMBV4 CGAS5 CMIG4 
 0.33  0.35  0.34
```

How can I manage to do this at once? I have to generate the same `list` with `33 matrices` but with only this constituents in each `matrix`. It has to be done for twenty percent of instead of 3 because the total amount varies for each of the `matrix` from the `list`.

Sorry for this probably stupid question. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have 2 matrices instead of 33 for this.

It can easily be done with lappy:

```
a <- matrix(c(0.44, 0.33, 0.43, 0.54, 0.42, 0.49, 0.48, 0.51, 0.48, 0.55, 0.35, 0.51, 0.50, 0.34, 0.37), 1,15)
colnames(a) <- c("ACES4", "AMBV4", "ARCZ6", "BBAS3", "BBDC4", "BRAP4", "BRKM5", "BRTP3", "BRTP4", "CESP5", "CGAS5", "CLSC4", "CMIG3", "CMIG4", "DASA3")
b <- matrix(c(0.49, 0.33, 0.43, 0.54, 0.62, 0.49, 0.48, 0.51, 0.58, 0.55, 0.35, 0.51, 0.50, 0.34, 0.37), 1,15)
colnames(b) <- c("ACES4", "AMBV4", "ARCZ6", "BBAS3", "BBDC4", "BRAP4", "BRKM5", "BRTP3", "BRTP4", "CESP5", "CGAS5", "CLSC4", "CMIG3", "CMIG4", "DASA3")

mylist<-list(a,b)


c <- lapply(mylist, function(x) { as.matrix(x[ x < quantile(x,0.2)])})


    > c
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] 0.33
[2,] 0.35
[3,] 0.34

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,] 0.33
[2,] 0.35
[3,] 0.34

> is.matrix(c[[1]])
[1] TRUE
>
```

As you can see a list is produced with each element being the min 20% values of each individual matrix. Also, each element for example `c[[1]]` is a matrix.

Thus, you will end up with a list containing 33 matrices with only the 20% min values.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you again! Could you recommend some good reading for beginners in R? I see I'm doing a lot of basic/stupid questions in here!

Comment: You are welcome :) It is always a pleasure :) Questions are never stupid as long as they are asked in a clear way, like you did here and in your previous questions. I find that Stack Overflow is a very good place to learn from beginner to advanced and believe me I had 10 times more 'stupid' questions when I began than yours. As for a book I over-enjoyed two books: [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Machine-Learning-R-Brett-Lantz/dp/1782162143)

Comment: and [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Applied-Predictive-Modeling-Max-Kuhn/dp/1461468485/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1412630080&sr=8-1&keywords=Applied+Predictive+Modeling). Both of them are for machine learning though. The first one has an introductory level about R, the second is a bit more advanced. However, these are focused on machine learning so I don't know if this is something you are interested in. I can only recommend books that I have read to be honest and these are two books I have and I really feel they are great to recommend.

Comment: I just checked [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginners-Guide-Use-Alain-Zuur/dp/0387938362), too. I haven't read it but the contents seem good and it has good reviews. This is for a beginner and it's only about programming with R. You might wanna check it.

Comment: I've never heard about machine learning but it seems interesting! I believe it will be helpful to my studies in economics and econometrics. Tks!

Answer (score 1):

base R

```
a[a <= quantile(a, 0.2)]
[1] 0.33 0.35 0.34
```

dplyr

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
b <- as.tbl(melt(a))
b %>%
  filter(value, percent_rank(value) < .2)
#    Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#
#  Var1  Var2 value
#1    1 AMBV4  0.33
#2    1 CGAS5  0.35
#3    1 CMIG4  0.34
```